# How to mimic php crypt() on NODE.JS

Tags: php, javascript, node.js, encryption, des

Please help with php -> javascript(node.js) conversion

```
$key = crypt($key, $salt);
```

I'm rewriting php script with node.js, and I got stuck with hash signature generation in php, which is made using crypt() function with salt matching "CRYPT_EXT_DES" pattern

> CRYPT_EXT_DES - Extended DES-based hash. The "salt" is a 9-character string consisting of an underscore followed by 4 bytes of iteration count and 4 bytes of salt. These are encoded as printable characters, 6 bits per character, least significant character first. The values 0 to 63 are encoded as "./0-9A-Za-z". Using invalid characters in the salt will cause crypt() to fail.

I'm not really experienced with encryption, and studying node.js docs on crypto module didnt help. Please help how to implement this on node.js!

Comment: what code have you tried?

Comment: Nothing, I dont know where to start really. crypto's createHash/createHMac/createSign doesnt support "DES" algorithm on my machine, it's available only for cipher in numerous variations, but php's crypt() is one-way string hashing, not supposed to be deciphered, so I guess cipher is not the right tool.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the [crypt(3)](https://github.com/sendanor/node-crypt3) library should work.

E.g.:

```
const crypt = require( 'crypt3/sync' ),
      key = "password",
      hash = crypt( key, crypt.createSalt( 'sha512' ) );
```

And then to test stored hash...

```
const crypt = require( 'crypt3/sync' ),
      key = "password",
      hash = /* stored hash */;

if ( crypt( key, hash ) !== hash ) {
  // access denied
  return false;
}
```

(six year late, I know)

Comment: Six years late, but not supported by node higher than 8 version :D

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with https://github.com/thomas-alrek/node-php-password

```
var Password = require("node-php-password");

var options = {
    cost: 10,
    salt: "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxc"
};
const hashedPassword = Password.hash(password, "PASSWORD_DEFAULT", options);
```

and this will be the same result as in php

```
crypt(password,'$2y$10$'.'qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxc'.'$')
```